# Android : simulate / mimic a call programmatically on device

Tags: android

Is it possible to simulate or mimic a call coming in on an Android device programmatically from the device (not connected to a computer)?  I am doing a safety demo about the dangers of calls while driving and I would prefer not to have to create my own copy of the call app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can!

Use adb for that, for emulators you can also use the android-studio tools.

```
adb -s <serial> shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:0612345678
```

Where `<serial>` should be your device or emulator id (like emulator-5555)

If you want to do it on the device itself, you can try to call yourself (yes it kind of works on most devices).

Comment: I need to do this actually from the device

Comment: Try to call yourself.

Comment: You can get a list of connected devices by using `adb devices`. There will be a serial number you need

Comment: This makes a call from the device, it does not simulate an incoming call.